# Как сделать полукруглую фигуру?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался делать вот таким образом, но форма и размер всё равно не те. Не могу подогнать под нужные размеры:

```css
#container {
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.view-catalog {
  left: 57%;
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
}
.view-catalog:before,
.view-catalog:after {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
  font-size: 100pt;
  text-indent: 30px;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 300px;
}
.view-catalog:before {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 20px 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(69deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(69deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
}
.view-catalog:after {
  left: -275px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-69deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotate(-69deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 30px 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
  line-height: 550px;
  content: "";
  font-size: 130pt;
  text-indent: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="view-catalog"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А для чего этот головняк на css? я как-то запаривался когда делать нечего было, чистым css без единой картинки http://codepen.io/AntonEssenetial/pen/trlfu  но тут, какой в этом смысл? делать это на css? по моему это боль, или вы просто хотите понять можно или нет или просто научиться? Мне кажется проще png резануть.